# Netbeans C++ trys a relative path for make.exe

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, g++, mingw

I recently reinstalled Windows on one PC but I'm failing in reinstalling Netbeans C++ with MinGw/Msys and Qt 4.8.3. Everytime I try to build a error message like this comes up:

```
"/d/Eigene Dateien/Dokumente/NetBeansProjects/Test_1/"C:/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=/C/Qt/4.8.3/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

/bin/sh.exe: /d/Eigene Dateien/Dokumente/NetBeansProjects/Test_1/C:/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe: No such file or directory
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 127


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 964ms)
```

It seems for me that it trys to execute the commands relativly to the project path. On my laptop I did everything same when I installed Netbeans 7.2.1 (now it's 7.3, maybe cause of that?) and hadn't this issue.

Comment: Have you had this figured out? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: No, it seems to me that it is a bug in netbeans; i switched to the qt creator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug caused by Java 7u21 in Netbeans 7.3. See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228730. One workaround, if you do not want to upgrade (although I don't see why anyone would not want to upgrade) is to add msys' bin directory to the path, and then use `make.exe` as the command for make (as opposed to C:\msys\bin\make.exe or wherever it is installed).

That being said, the best solution is to just upgrade to Netbeans 7.3.1, where the bug seems to be fixed, along with many more bugs.

Comment: This is not unique to 7.3. I am experiencing this in 7.3.1 as well.

Comment: On 8.2, still have this issue.

Comment: I do too... Is it an issue with using 32bit java with 64bit everything else?

Answer (score 2):

If there is no make.exe in `C:\msys\1.0\bin` you should use ?:\minGW\bin\make.exe.

ALso your Netbeans Options should have the path to the make exe.

[image]

Comment: There is a make.exe in C:/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe that's why wrote that it seams to execute the command relativly to the project directory.

Comment: So change the Netbeans setting as discriped above to C:\mingw\bin\make.exe .

Comment: there is only a mingw32-make.exe and Netbeans says I should use the make.exe from mysys

Answer (score 0):

If you have your path rigth configured (you can open your console and execute make.exe form anywhere on the path) you can put just "make.exe" (without path) on "Make Command" option in C/C++ netbean configuration.